# Wordpress global $menu not showing all menu items in a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, menu, admin

I have created a php function which changes some wp admin menu item names. When I added this code to the function.php of my custom theme it works perfectly. But when I added the same code to a custom plugin, I cannot get all the menu items. I can only edit the main wp admin menu items like posts, pages, settings, plugins, etc. But not the other plugin menu items.

The code:

```
if (!function_exists('admin_menu_rename')) {
  function admin_menu_rename() {
    global $menu, $submenu;
    if ($menu) {
      foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
        if ($value[0] == "originalname") {
          var_dump($key);
          $menu[$key][0] = "newname";
          $menu[$key][6] = "other icon";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'admin_menu_rename' );
}
```

Why is this code working fine in the themes function.php but not fully functional in the plugin file?

Comment: Because the code from the function.php executes after all plugins have initialized. Whereas when you are doing this inside of a specific plugin, other plugins that manipulate the menu structure, might not have run yet. You can try and increase the _priority_ of the action you are adding there; if that does not help, then you will probably have to look into the execution order and what exactly the other plugins are doing, in a bit more detail.

Comment: Or, find a different action to hook your code into. The function you have shown does not appear to need any specific parameters passed from the `admin_menu` hook caller, but works on global variables only - so it should be able to work using any other action instead. Maybe `plugins_loaded` does the job.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for answering. I tried the hook plugins_loaded but that one doesn't work either. Then I tried your first solution changing the priority and that does the trick. Stupid of me not to think about that. Thanks for all the help!